# How to get German locale to work in Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jsfiddle

I've got the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) running in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/wfq7ndnx/6/) but I can't get the German locale to work:

```
$('#monthpicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: '2015-09',
    format: 'MMM YYYY',
    locale: 'de'
});
```

and have these two resources loaded that I understand I need:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js

But it gives me this error:

> TypeError: a.fn.datepicker is undefined
>
> TypeError: locale() locale de is not loaded from moment locales!

**What do I have to do to get the German locale to work?**

Comment: I've used this datepicker quite a bit and have wrestled it a lot. Can I ask if you have been able to get any locales to work besides 'de'?

Comment: Any feedback on this issue?

Answer (score 9):

[Bootstrap DatePicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is totally another javascript control.

*You seem to be using the locale of this one.*

[Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) can be found [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) on github.
It uses moment and moment's locales.
You only need to reference:

- bootstrap-datetimepicker [javascript file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.15.35/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)
- bootstrap-datetimepicker [css file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.15.35/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css)
- [moment](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js)
- and your [locale](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/de.js) (or all the locales)

Of course, you need jquery and twitter bootstrap.

Once you're done with that you can use your locale like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'de',
    format: 'L',
    defaultDate: new Date('2015-09-01'),
    disabledDates: [
    moment("2015-12-25")]
});
```

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfq7ndnx/17/).